# Python: changing literal constructor behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

The basic question here is: if I subclass a base type (eg `list`), is it possible to have the interpreter use my subclass instead of `list` when I use a literal constructor?
Something like:

```py
class myList(list):
    pass

#default_for_[]=myList
l=[]
assert(isinstanceof(l, myList))
```

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Python is not Haskell with its polymorphic literals...

Answer (score 0):

Your basically asking if you can change how the python syntax works. And no, you can not do that. `[]` is built into python and will create an instance of a list no matter what you do. This is shown by reassigning `list` to your class.

```py
class myList(list):
    pass

list = myList  # changing the mapping
test = []
test2 = list()
print(type(test))
#  <class 'list'>
print(type(test2))
#  <class '__main__.myList'>
```

Comment: You're right, of course, but assigning `list = mylist` is hardly proof of anything. It would be slightly more convincing if you'd assign `builtins.list = mylist` instead. (Though it still wouldn't prove anything.)

Comment: How would changing the origin of the list make it more convincing? The ```list``` global refers to ```list``` in ```__builtins__``` does it not? I believe it proves it by saying that a call with ```[]``` produces a list behind the scenes, and not using mappings that are accessible at the module level. That is to say that even by changing how the local script maps a call to list, ```[]``` will be unaffected. I am probably missing something, but it seems to make sense in my head.

Comment: When you assign `list = mylist`, you're *creating* a `list` variable in the global scope. That variable doesn't usually exist, so it's not much of a surprise that it has no effect on list literals. By overriding `builtins.list` (rather than merely shadowing it with a global variable), you have better odds of python respecting your assignment. In theory, at least. In practice, it makes no difference.